# Getting REQUEST_DENIED on Google geocode API call from Python

Tags: python, geocoding

I am trying to geocode several thousand addresses using the Google geocode API from Python.  I am reusing code I wrote 2 years ago and for some reason it is throwing this error:

REQUEST_DENIED
{'error_message': 'The provided API key is invalid. ', 'results': [], 'status': 'REQUEST_DENIED'}

I have double and triple checked my API key.   I have pasted the URL i am using into a browser and it returns a valid response with coordinates of the address.   I thought it might be that I wasn't sending a user-agent so i added that and it doesn't help.   I have searched high and wide without luck.  Thoughts?

Request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIza.....JCqU4KPw&address=1741+E+64th+St+,+Los+Angeles,+CA+90001

I've obscured my key and the address

I have removed any use restrictions from my API key

Code:

```
import requests

geocode_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key={key}' \
          '&address={address}'

headers = {
  'User-Agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_3) '
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36'
}

...

address = (row['Address'] + ',+' + row['City'] + ',+' + 
           row['State'] + '+' + row['Zip']).replace(' ', '+')
geocode_url_values = geocode_url.format(address=address, key=API_Key)
results = requests.get(geocode_url, headers=request_headers)
results = results.json()
status = results['status']
```

Comment: would test via the official python code first. https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

Comment: Thank you, that works - just not sure why mine doesn't.  Will have to look at the source code.